# Why are the first two calculated data points in my "work script" zero?

Tags: r, physics

I am following a SMD analysis tutorial to write a script in R to compute and graph work in the Z direction. When my script runs through, the first two values are zero and they should not be...help?

```
#calcwork1.tcl#

n_time_steps <- 200

repeat {
   dz <- 0.1
  dW = dz*Fz
  W <- rep(0, n_time_steps + 1)
  W[1]
  dW[1]
  for (i in 2:n_time_steps + 1){
    W[i] <- W[i - 1] + dW[i - 1]
  }
  if (i == 201)
    break
}  


dz = 0.1
Fz = the force in the z direction
W = output work calculated
dW = change in work
n_time_steps = 200
```

Comment: (1) What is a good starting value for `Fz`? (2) Your use of `2:n_time_steps + 1` is vastly different from `2:(n_time_steps + 1)`, did you mean that instead? With that, W starts with `0, 0.1` (and all other 199 values are `NA`). (3) You say they are wrong and ask for help, but you don't tell us what values you expect. ???

Answer (score 1):

You don't need repeat. Assuming `Fz` is a normal, this works:

```
n_time_steps <- 200
Fz=rnorm(n_time_steps)

dz <- 0.1
dW = dz*Fz
W <- rep(0, n_time_steps + 1)
W[1]
dW[1]
for (i in 2:(n_time_steps + 1)){
  W[i] <- W[i - 1] + dW[i - 1]
}

plot(W[-1]~Fz)
plot(dW~W[-1])
```